# what is the best way to have the same image for the iphone and ipad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to make a game for the iphone and ipad. If i created a background image for the iphone how would i resize it to fit the ipad. Or would i have to make the same background image but with the ipad resolution.

Comment: you should use AutoLayout and add Constraint and use your Ratio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Put a `UIImageView` as the background image and set the desired image there.
2. Make the imageView cover the whole screen (end-to-end), using Autolayout or Auto sizing.
3. Set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;` You can do this in xib also. And voila!

Comment: what if i want to use a image that is not a background?

Comment: Then I don't think that there should be any issue. Please illustrate.

Comment: i am using spritekit and the image is going to be a spritenode. sorry if i am not explaining right.